# Show Confirmation dialog when Update linkbutton is clicked in GridView

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with rows of the gridview having an update linkbutton, an edit linkbutton, checkbox, dropdown list, and textboxes.

After the edit button is clicked and the checkbox is unchecked and the user clicks on the update linkbutton, I want to show a confirmation dialog with information from the dropdown list and textboxes.  If the user clicks on okay, the code for the gridview OnRowUpdating event should be raised.  And if the user clicks on cancel, nothing should happen.

I'm using the OnClientClick event of the update linkbutton to call a javascript function to show the confirmation dialog.  What I need to figure out is how to pass the checkbox value (true if the checkbox is checked and false if it's unchecked) and the textbox values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: by dialog can you just use the javascript confirm() function, which is synchronous, or do you have some other dialog technique? Makes a big difference.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey - I was thinking of using the confirm dialog. And I'd also like to pass parameters to the confirm dialog (if possible) with the checkbox, textbox, and dropdown list values.

Comment: show the code you've got so far. You'll have to format a string for the confirmation dialog, and to get the values you'll have to start from 'this' and go up the DOM, find the TR element, then down the DOM to find other controls.

Comment: To be honest, I don't have much. <asp:LinkButton ID="gvProductUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" OnClientClick="ConfirmDelete()"></asp:LinkButton> and function ConfirmDelete() {}

Comment: If the user is clicking on the update button for a specific GridviewRow, is it still required to traverse thru the DOM?